# can't import android.support.v4.app notificationcompat in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-notifications, android-support-library

I was learning android notification tutorial using [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTbd1Mfi-Sk&t=5s&ab_channel=CodinginFlow) but when I started using

```
 Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, App.CHANNEL_1_ID);
```

this code, I can't import android.support.v4.app. NotificationCompat , how to do that?
It only imports

```
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import android.app.Notification;
```

1. Do I need to add something in build.gradle?
2. I am using Android Studio 2021.1.1, is that the  problem?

Comment: whatever you are importing is right, what you are trying to import is outdated.

Comment: so support v4 library is outdated? or deprecated?

Comment: yeah deprecated, you can only use them if you have checked android.support when creating a project. and here are the equivalent artifacts name of android.support to androidx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

androidx is new support library for the replacement v4.support library. And androidx is recommended. I suggest you to use search filter to find tutorial later than 2020~2021.

However you can still use v4.support library by checking "Use legacy android.support library" option while creating a project.

[image]

While this is not enough, because latest build tools will not support deprecated libraries, you have to keep compleSdkVersion 28 or below. You are also required to downgrade your Android Gradle Plugin to 3.6.4 and gradle wrapper to 6.0

Make sure these lines are not present in gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Now you can follow the above tutorial.

Use

```
android.arch.core:core
android.arch.core:common

instead of 

androidx.arch.core:core-common
androidx.arch.core:core
```

[Here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings) is the full list of equivalent artifacts of support library to androidx

I do not recommend you to follow above tutorial find latest tutorial. Tech is rapidly changing, following an outdated tutorial might slow your learning process and keep you behind.